# Displaying image from sd card

Tags: android, imageview

I use this code

```
    String imgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/p1.png";
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
    image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

but imageview's background isn't p1.png there is no image at the background it is white please help.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path of the SDCard. Then you can do normal I/O-Operations just like this:

```
String imgFile = String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "p1.png";
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);r code here
```